# Генерация нескольких deb пакетов из одного проекта

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, deb

может ли cmake от одного проекта сгенерировать 2 разных deb пакета?
в проекте у меня клиент и сервер. Если генерацию deb пакета одному только прописать - создаются. А если обоим прописать только клиенту. Не могу найти как это исправить. Нашел только - что нужно прописать компоненты - но это не совсем то. Сталкивался кто?

```
install(TARGETS ${SERVER_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME ${SERVER_NAME})
set(CPACK_GENERATOR DEB)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT dddddddd@yandex.ru)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON)
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)

include(CPack)
```

Comment: Попробуйте разные `project` указать

Comment: @dIm0n для CPack можно как-то проект указать? или Вы о другом?

Comment: Я про https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html

Comment: а, ну это само собой сделал